# Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster needs access to port 1433

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, amazon-web-services

Using [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Extensions.foreign-data-wrappers.html) as a guide I am trying to configure PostgreSQL tds_fdw extension to access my MS SQL Server RDS.
I am getting the similar error message specified in that article:

> ERROR: DB-Library error: DB #: 20009, DB Msg: Unable to connect:
> Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (mssql2019.aws-region.rds.amazonaws.com), OS #: 0, OS Msg: Success, Level: 9

The solution also provided. Which is :

> You also need to provide access on the security group or the access control list (ACL) for the SQL Server port, 1433. Both the Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster and the RDS for SQL Server DB instance need access to port 1433.

But I can't figure out where and how should I configure my Aurora PostgreSQL instance to access that port 1433 while still having a default one in place.

Please advise.

Comment: What does your `CREATE SERVER` statement look like in PostgreSQL? Are you using the correct `tds_version` parameter? (SQL Server 2019 uses TDS 7.4.)

Comment: PostgreSQL needs permission for outbound access to 1433, MSSQL for inbound access.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning
IDK That was the only one available I guess.

Comment: @jjanes
I'd be happy to learn how to do this, plz. I mean how to setup outbound 1433 for AWS Aurora PostgreSQL. Thx in advance.

Comment: You use the security group editor to edit the security group.  You can probably find a youtube video where someone demonstrates it you need to, I'm surely not a videographer.

Comment: @jjanes
And you prolly mean AWS security group at this point I assume, right?
Sorry for asking that many questions. I spent several hours "googling" prior to ask this question here.

Comment: @jjanes
If you familiar with the topic would you plz confirm that the link I presented gives what I'm looking for?
[Controlling access with security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html)

Comment: Yes, that is the security group I am talking about.  It is possible that that is already set up correctly and the problem is with something else, the error message is regrettably vague..  I'd try to connect with a simple command line tool, like tsql I guess, to see if it works, and if not if it gives a better message.

Comment: @jjanes
Thank Ya very much indeed. I will give it a try.